# Lightning:tab accesskey and tabindex not working

Tags: lightning-tab

Lightning:tab (beta) has **accesskey** and **tabindex** attributes, however it seems to be not working properly. The **tabindex** tag doesn't show the correct index and the **accesskey** is not available when inspecting the html generated. Has anyone run into the same problem?

Code example:

```
<lightning:tabset aura:id="tabset" variant="default" selectedTabId="searchTab1">
    <lightning:tab aura:id="searchTab1" tabindex="1" id="searchTab1" accesskey="f" title='Keyboard shortcut is "f"' >
        <aura:set attribute="label">
            <p class="slds-p-horizontal_x-large">Tab1</p>
        </aura:set>
        ...
```

Comment: I think tabindex is effectively a read-only property that's ultimately controlled by the tabset (use a few tabs and observe what happens). Not sure why accesskey isn't working, though. Maybe there's a bug, or it only works when the content is in focus... Further investigation would be required.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox! I guess it's a bug, even using the most simple scenario and pressing the tab button to jump between different elements, the tabs are being totally ignored. The tabindex is "-1" or "0" when nothing is defined. I've created a Salesforce case (support) to address this issue. I'll keep an eye on it and I'll share more details once I receive it.

Comment: The case has been forwarded to SFDC R&D team for further analysis and confirmation, but they were able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sweet! Hopefully they get it sorted out, that's a pretty big issue. The UI is not keyboard friendly at all.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce confirmed that as a bug, they have provided the following Known Issue article: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p3A000000mDOp

Also, they replied the information below:
"R&D team has filed a bug and are working further on the same. 
This should be fixed based on the planning done by R&D in **upcoming releases / patches (Safe Harbor)**."